# Is There A Way To Connect and Auto-fill Data in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've tried looking this up with no avail, but I'm attempting to set up an auto-fill that works like a search engine but for limited searches. For instance if I write the word Ashley, I'd like it to fill in the cell beside it with a string of numbers. I work in a job with many showrooms and numbers that need to be organized but I'd like to be able to search by either the name or number associated and have it auto-fill the former or latter.

I'm unsure if Excel can even do this, but if it's possible please explain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VLOOKUP() for this.

First create a table of names and strings. (Put this in columns A and B, starting at row 1)

```
Ashley aaaaAaaAAa
Ryan   bbbbBbbBBb
Megan  ccccCccCCc
```

Move to cell A7 and type the value "Ashley" or "aaaaAaaAAa".

In cell B7 paste:

```
=VLOOKUP(A7,A1:B3,2,FALSE)
```

In cell C7 paste

```
=VLOOKUP(A7,A1:B3,1,FALSE)
```

The arguments in VLOOKUP are used in the following way:

1 - looks at the cell you want to evaluate

2 - is the table of data with answers

3 - returns the associated data from this column

4 - TRUE returns the closest match, FALSE only returns an exact match